# Tooltip not working google pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a pie chart like bellow,everything works fine except the tool tip. I need to redesign the tool tip design with my custom html.but it does not show the tag as i expect.It shows html as string.Please see the fiddle.....

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
        data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
        data.addRows([
          ['Work', 11,'<p>tooltip 1</p>'],
          ['Eat', 2,'<p>tooltip 1</p>'],
          ['Commute', 2,'<p>tooltip 1</p>'],
          ['Watch TV', 2,'<p>tooltip 1</p>'],
         
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add option "tooltip: {isHtml: true}" too

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
        data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html':true}}); 
        data.addRows([
          ['Work', 11,'<p>tooltip 1</p>'],
          ['Eat', 2,'<p>tooltip 1</p>'],
          ['Commute', 2,'<p>tooltip 1</p>'],
          ['Watch TV', 2,'<p>tooltip 1</p>'],
         
        ]);

        var options = {
          tooltip: {isHtml: true}, //Add this line
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: I can't see any difference between my question and your answer,both creates same result.

Comment: I'm sorry, please modify this line of code too:

data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});

To

data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});

Answer (score 1):

You can convert HTML string into DOM elements by Javascript Dom parser like below code:

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var Converter = new DOMParser();
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
    data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip' });
    data.addRows([
        ['Work', 11, Converter.parseFromString("<p>tooltip 1</p>", "text/html")],
        ['Eat', 2, Converter.parseFromString("<p>tooltip 1</p>", "text/html")],
        ['Commute', 2, Converter.parseFromString("<p>tooltip 1</p>", "text/html")],
        ['Watch TV', 2, Converter.parseFromString("<p>tooltip 1</p>", "text/html")],
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```